# Update query is running forever and at the end session is out

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was trying to update the table having rows "5013839981",The update query is running for forever at the end I am getting an error message
"Statement reached its statement or warehouse timeout of 3,600 second(s) and was canceled."
Here is the sample of table

I am trying to update the table1 with table2 column "sc" here is my

```
table1

CP
stab
crawl
dred
sab
table2

CP  SC
stab    stab
crawl   crawl.com
dred    dredal
sab sab
```

So I was trying to update column table1 "CP", If table2 CP<>SC then to update table1 CP with SC else CP the common field in both table is cp,The execution time is going on infinite while trying below query.

So here is the update query which I am trying

```
update table1 set table1.cp = source.sc
from (select * from table2 where cp <> sc ) source
where table1.cp = source.cp;
```

Comment: Can you share the execution plan of your query?

Comment: I need to update the table 1 with the sc table where table1.cp=table2.cp and table1.cp<>table2.sp,Since there is a large amount of data I am not able to update it, the query runs for more than hour after it gets canceled with an error, The query I am using is above

Comment: I got it but I need to see the execution plan to understand why its spending so much time